# Deleting directories in bash

Tags: git, bash

This is a simple command: `rm -rf dir` But i have an interesting problem to solve. My bash script calls `composer install` on a composer script, this then makes `vendor/app-name/` in the directory the `composer install` was run in. which is fine, the problem is I am now doing something like:

```
cp -R /vendor/ . 
# I believe this is correct for copying everything 
# out out of vendor and into root
```

to copy everything from vendor. Ok that's define, but there could be 300 app-name folders in there (obviously all with different names other then app-name), each might have a `.gitignore`, `.git` directory or a documentation Directory. I want to say:

*Walk through each of the folders, looking for .git/, .gitignore or Documentation and delete them if found.*

How can I do this in bash?

**note:** All the packages that are being pulled down are pulled down via git, how ever the user may choose to add additional ones pulled down from composer package land. the same concepts should still apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove all of **.git/**, **.gitignore**, or **Documentation** you can try:

```
find \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Comment: I had never used -o before, good to have learned something today :-)

Comment: I would add `-type d` to the arguments passed to `find`. Also the pathname is missing (should go right before the first option).

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou, note that `-a` (which means "and") is *implied* between "testing" options.  Another not-widely-understood thing is that the `-exec` family of options also provides *tests, not actions,* that is, if `rm` in that `-exec` test fails, the test evaluates to false, otherwise it evaluates to true, so if one wants to fail early, one should write `-exec rm -f {} \; -o -quit` (`find` would exit with code 0 anyway, but I digress...).

Comment: @kostix since the asker's restriction isn't include type, I've omitted that. I believe the files `.git` should be also removed =)

Comment: @kostix very interesting about the exec part. As for the '-type d', the '.gitignore' he/she wants to delete is actually a file.

Answer (score 3):

Probably there's a better way, but off the top of my head I would do this:

```
find . -type d -iname .git | xargs rm -rf
find . -type f -iname .gitignore | xargs rm
find . -type d -iname Documentation | xargs rm -rf
```

First line deletes all folders named .git, second line all files named .gitignore, third line all folders named Documentation.

Comment: You can also use the `-exec` option to `find` as in `find . -type d -iname .git -exec rm -rf {} \;` Note the escaped `;`. If you don't escape it, it won't work.